# mvn dependencies same version with different jars

Tags: java, maven

I created a private library that I include on some of my projects. That library is called `processor`.
This library is deployed using maven on a private artifactory repository.

Each time I deploy the library with an existing version number, it adds a new jar with an incremental number at the end.

For example here is the content of my `.m2/repository/my-domain/processor`:
[image]

I've built my application with the `processor-1.4-4.jar` once but now the version is `1.4-12.jar`. I would like maven to recognize their is multiple jars of a single library and take the latest.

What I've tried:

- resync dependencies
- `mvn clean`
- `mvn package`
- `mvn compile`
- `mvn install`
- rebuild project

But it will always take the `1.4-4` jar and not `1.4-12` one.

Is their a way to tell maven to get the latest jar ?
Or is it wrong to deploy multiple times with the same version ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Deleting and reimporting dependency resolve the issue but I would like to now if their is a better way of handling this and/or if its a bad practice or not. Thanks.

Comment: The date added means it is a snapshot release and not a stable release. Stable releases are performed either by the maven release plugin or by uploading a version of the processor jar without -snapshot in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits goes to @JF Meier thanks to his comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/60453689/3520621

The solution was `mvn package -U` + reimport maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you build a jar with version `1.4-SNAPSHOT`. This is a development version from which you can deploy as many as you want. Each new deployment is stored in Artifactory with a new timestamp.

When you add a dependency in your project that references `1.4-SNAPSHOT`, you get the latest of those versions in Artifactory (unless you build a newer version locally).

Comment: Actually I got the version "4" of the 1.4-SNAPSHOT when I do a `mvn package` which is not the latest one. The latest timestamp is the version "12" of `1.4-SNAPSHOT`. 
And in fact I'm aware that this is a development version and it's intended as the library is still in an alpha stage.

Comment: `mvn package -U` + reimport maven dependencies was the trick for me. Thanks.